# VIM move to a word starting with a character

Tags: vim

we can use f command in VIM to move to any character in a line. But most of the times i want to move to start of a word. Is there any existing command similar to f to jump to a word starting with a particular character. Or tell me how to how to create one?

Comment: please first tell why are you not satisfied with `f` for your needs.

Comment: @Kent "start of a word"

Comment: @Bernhard ok..  sure, I think I know what he wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EasyMotion plugin could do what you need. you can `<leader><leader>w` and press the index letter.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion

Answer (score 1):

How about <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (here word start with a)
Now <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> to jump next or previous.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely fail safe, but <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will do the trick, i.e. search for a space followed by your character.

If the boundary of the word is not only spaces, you could choose to use `\<` instead of <kbd>Space</kbd>

Via `:help \<`

> \< Matches the beginning of a word: The next char is the first char of a word.  The 'iskeyword' option specifies what is a word character.